# Is this a reasonable approach for my Java web app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, architecture

Just wondering if there is a better approach to building to the web app that I'm creating? I'm not going to show a lot of code, I'm more interested in following best practices:

1. `Index.html` contains a static form
2. User fills out the form and the POST request is handled by a Java Servlet
3. The servlet contains 3 methods:

   - `doPost(HttpRequest, 
     HttpResponse)`
   - `doGet(HttpRequest, HttpResponse)`
   - `processRequest(Map map)`
4. `doPost()` constructs a hashmap and assigns all of the variables from the form to it in `key:value` format. Then it calls the method `processRequest(Map map)`
5. `processRequest(Map map)` has one function: to create a new instance of class `formParser` with the map variable: i.e. `formParser parser = new formParser(map);`
6. The class `formParser` has a constructor and a method:

   - the constructor initializes a new HashMap which clones the original and a new LinkedList which is to store the values and calls the method with the map parameter

     ```
     Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
     List<String> paramList = getParams(paramMap);
     ```
   - The method `public LinkedList<String> getParams(Map paramMap)` then checks all of the key:value pairs in the map and only takes those that have no `null` values
7. I then use the valid key:value pairs to write certain XML snippets to a pre-existing XML skeleton, which is sent to an external REST-API. I have yet to write this code.

EDIT: I should add that I'm new to Java Web programming, and this is why I'm only trying to validate the efficacy of my approach to the program, rather than the code itself. That will come later.

Comment: Can we see your code? Obviously Step 7 can be more efficient; since you haven't even written the code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not concerned yet with Step 7. I want to make sure that what I've done so far is a good approach that's all. You pretty much have my code there, there's very little else to add

Comment: Maybe you can just move out "null" parameters from client side (with some JavaScript). So you did not need to do this stuff on Java side.

Comment: @sk2212 I was thinking of this alternative already. I was going to create a dynamic form in JavaScript so that the user only sees form fields based on their previous selections. It may be a better approach

Comment: Efficiency doesn't matter.  If you're new to Java web programming, just get it working and worry about efficiency later.  There are a million good web frameworks out there (e.g. Spring).  You could learn from them even if you wanted to write it on your own.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "efficiency".  It is run-time performance, scalability, or minimal amount of source code?

Comment: @HDave ok on reading your comment I now realize that I should have said something like best practice, rather than efficient. I just want to ensure that my approach would be considered 'good programming'. I don't want to be creating unnecessary classes/methods or overhead etc.

Comment: @adohertyd - no problem.  I'll edit to clarify and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that step 6 can be improved a little by not creating the LinkedList. If I understand correctly the LinkedList is used to remove NULL values. This can be achieved by iterating over the keys of the map, retrieving their value and removing any keys from the map that have NULL values.

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name1","somevalue");
map.put("name2",null);

for(String s : map.keySet()){ 
    String value = map.get(s);
        if ( s == null){
            map.remove(s);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I want to ensure that when I am programming that I do it correctly and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you exactly mean by "efficiency", but if you are talking about performance, I don't see anything crazy being done in the steps you describe, and IMO that's enough.

Go with the simplest, most usual design and you can improve performance if there is a problem. In my experience, 99.999% of performance problems in web apps come from doing crazy stuff (i.e. unusual, complex approaches).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to web programming you should not consider performance problems.

Just focus on working code.